# SPFx: pnp.sp.search result how to search by date

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

I'm using pnp.sp.serach to search files and folders.

I need to search by file's and folder's date.

I see results have properties LastModifiedTime, but the value came undefined.

```
 pnp.sp.search({
                Querytext: query,
                RowLimit: 20,
                StartRow: 0,
                SelectProperties: ["Title", "Author", "Path", "FileType", "RefinersTextListOWSTEXT"]
            })

                .then((results) => {
                    results.PrimarySearchResults.forEach((result) => {
                        _results.push({
                            title: result.Title,
                            description: result.HitHighlightedSummary,
                            link: result.Path,
                            author: result.Author,
                            filetype: result.FileType,
                            path: result.OriginalPath,
                            date: result.LastModifiedTime
                        });
                    });
                })
                .then(
                    () => { resolve(_results); }
                )
                .catch(
                    () => { reject(new Error("Error")); }
                );
```

Comment: Did you try to add LastModifiedTime into selected properties?

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela Yes, I tried, it came undefined

Comment: Can you try using this managed property: `ModifiedOWSDATE`? Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes, it is work!
I made like this
`SelectProperties: ["Title", "Author", "Path", "FileType", "RefinersTextListOWSTEXT","ModifiedOWSDATE"]`

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: Would it work for you if you use query like "* LastModifiedTime>2023-01-15" to get result that already fall into your dates frame instead of getting all results and then selecting what you need by date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use managed property named `ModifiedOWSDATE` instead of `LastModifiedTime`.

It will give you the modified date in search results. Use `SelectProperties` like:

```
SelectProperties: ["Title", "Author", "Path", "FileType", "RefinersTextListOWSTEXT", "ModifiedOWSDATE"]
```

And then you can get the value in success callback using:

```
date: result.ModifiedOWSDATE
```